# rewrite breaks svn

Tags: svn, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite that's based of HTTP_USER_AGENT, for various reasons I can't put svn in the root but need to have it on /svn

The rules right now is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SVN
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /svn/$1 [L]
```

And the location-definition is:

```
  <Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SvnPath /home/subgit/repos/testrepo
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "subgit"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/subgit/etc/subgit
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/subgit/etc/subgit.access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
```

However trying to access this with the SVN client I get the following result:

> svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://server.tld/trunk'
>   svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the
>   response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found
>   (http://server.tld/trunk)

Removing the rule and querying /svn/trunk works fine though.

Thanks

Comment: A test you can do is loading the URL in a regular browser (comment out the User Agent check to do so).

Answer (score 3):

First of all the request is never getting to mod_dav_svn because by default mod_rewrite treats the substitution as a file path and not a URI.  Since it's not a URI the Location section doesn't match.  You can use the `PT` flag on `RewriteRule` in order to treat the substitution as a URI and thus allow it to get to SVN:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt

However, even if you add the `PT` flag you're going to run into another problem. Specifically an error about the URL not being the same repository.  That's because the server provides URIs to the client and the client has realized that the the URIs that SVN is providing is not a child of the repository root URL it has discovered.

Your attempt to detect a SVN server based on the UserAgent isn't really guaranteed to work.  Most SVN clients are using the subversion projects libraries, however there are several independent implementations that may or may not follow that pattern.

Ultimately, rewriting or redirecting the URI just won't work with Subversion.  The protocol is just not friendly to that.  I'd recommend just using `/svn/trunk`.

Comment: +1 from me. I just ran into the same problem today, subversion 1.8.11 with Apache 2.2.27. Even with [PT] flag, the svn client asserts "http://.../XXX isn't in the same repository as http://.../YYY"